# How do I authenticate a management service request to Windows Azure?

Tags: python, ssl, azure, ssl-certificate

I am trying to make a request to Azure via Python to list the storage services I have.

My base code is this:

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('management.core.windows.net')
conn.request('GET', '/[subscription id]/services/storageservices/')
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status response.reason
```

Obviously, because I did not authenticate, this printed out `403 Forbidden`

So, I followed the instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg651127 to create a cert, giving me `cert.cer`. I uploaded my `.cer` to my Azure account and copied the `.cer` to my Linux VM in which I am using Python. I modified my code to be:

```
import httplib
cert_file = '/path/to/cert.cer'
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('management.core.windows.net', cert_file = cert_file)
conn.request('GET', '/[subscription id]/services/storageservices/')
```

and got the error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 336265225] _ssl.c:351: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib
```

Under the impression that maybe this was because I was trying to use a `.cer` certificate instead of a `.pem`, and based on what is said [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file) about the difference between .pem's and .cer's *(that they're the same thing with a different extension)*, I just changed the extension on my .cer to a .pem and tried again, getting the same error.

How can I properly authenticate myself to Azure to access its API? Is this an issue with how I am uploading the certificate, or do I need to do something with the certificate to make it suitable to present to the server? On Windows it seems I can install the `.cer` into some sort of certificate store - is there an equivalent in Linux from which I need to retrieve the cert before using it to authenticate? Thanks for any help =)

Comment: Is your second code sample missing something? I don't see where you're using the variable `cert_file`. You're on the right track, and I suspect you're right that it's a file format issue.

Comment: whoops, fixed it, thanks for the catch. Yeah, the sample project provided at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg651127.aspx works perfectly... I'm not totally clear on how certs are stored and ssl auth works, but I think it might be some friction with the way I'm getting the cert and adding it to the request that's causing the issue, given the fancy way it's done in the sample lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some working Python code, but as you noted, the trick is getting the right PEM files:

```
import httplib

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('management.core.windows.net', cert_file='cert.pem', key_file='key.pem')
conn.request('GET', '/%s/services/storageservices' % subscription_id, headers={'x-ms-version': '2011-02-25'})
print conn.getresponse().read()
```

I got my PEM files from https://github.com/smarx/waz-cmd, a Ruby-based command-line tool I wrote to interact with the Service Management API. Note that you need both pieces (the `cert_file` and the `key_file`).

You have the cert file already, though I think you may actually need to convert it via something like `openssl` to PEM format. For the key file, I think you'll need to export the certificate you created on your Windows machine and then use `openssl` to export the private key as a PEM file.

These days, instead of creating your own certificate, you can download a `.publishsettings` file from the Windows Azure portal, which generates and gives you a certificate that's ready to go. See http://blog.smarx.com/posts/calling-the-windows-azure-service-management-api-with-the-new-publishsettings-file. The certificate in there is in PFX format, but the right `openssl` magic should give you the two pieces you need. I actually solved this problem once (for use with `curl` on a Mac), but I no longer have the exact commands handy. :-( I *may* give it a whirl and write a blog post about it this evening.

**EDIT**:

Here's a complete Python program that takes a `.publishsettings` file on the command-line, dumps the key and certificate into a single file (cert.pem) in the current directory, and then uses it to call the service management API and print the names of all your storage accounts. Before running, just `pip install lxml pyopenssl`.

```
import httplib
import argparse
from StringIO import StringIO
from lxml import etree
import base64
from OpenSSL.crypto import *

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file', metavar='file', type=str, help='Your .publishsettings file.')
args = parser.parse_args()

tree = etree.parse(args.file)
pp = tree.find('PublishProfile')
cert = load_pkcs12(base64.decodestring(pp.get('ManagementCertificate')))
with open('cert.pem', 'w') as f:
    f.write(dump_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM, cert.get_certificate()))
    f.write(dump_privatekey(FILETYPE_PEM, cert.get_privatekey()))
subscription_id = pp.find('Subscription').get('Id')

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('management.core.windows.net', cert_file='cert.pem')
conn.request('GET', '/%s/services/storageservices' % subscription_id, headers={'x-ms-version': '2011-02-25'})
for e in etree.parse(StringIO(conn.getresponse().read())).iterfind('//{http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure}ServiceName'): print e.text
```

Comment: BTW, if you want to stick with the certificate you generated, you should just be able to export it as a PFX and then use `cert = load_pkcs12(the_pfx_contents)` instead.

Comment: I did write up a blog post on this: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/wa-smapi-python. I changed the code there a bit, mostly in a failed attempt to make it Windows-friendly.

Comment: To follow up about what seems to have been the original issue - comparing the cert created by your code to the cert created by makecert, it seems the .cer I received from that was encoded using DER, but when I reexported it using Base_64 so I could view it in plaintext - it only had the certificate component and not the private key. Looking at the cert in MMC (the MSFT MGMT CNSL), the cert definitely was generated with a private key, but I'm still unsure how to export it alone or together with the cert.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Import-or-export-certificates-and-private-keys?

Comment: This references the same snap in I used in MMC... However, I eventually did figure out how to get a usable cert from the one I initially created, I'll detail how that worked in an additional answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

This is how I converted the cert I created in my question into a format I could use to authenticate my requests to the Azure Service Management API. Smarx's answer also works, and indeed I used the cert created by his technique involving the `.publishsettings` file to figure out how my converted cert should look.

Create your cert by opening up the Visual Studio Command Prompt and typing:

```
makecert -r -pe -a sha1 -n "CN=My Azure Management Certificate" -ss My -len 2048 -sp   
"Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -sy 24 myazuremanagementcert.cer
```

as directed by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg651127.

Then, open up the Certificate Manager by typing `certmgr.msc` into the search box. I found my certificate under `Certificates - Current User/Personal/Certificates`.

Right-clicking on the certificate, go to "All Tasks" and click "Export". When prompted, make sure "Yes, export the private key" is selected and export the file as a .PFX (PKCS#12).

Here, I moved my .PFX to a Linux VM.

Everything from here on follows the steps laid out at http://blog.scottlowe.org/2005/12/02/certificate-conversion-using-openssl/

Opening a terminal, type:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in pfxfilename.pfx -out tempfile.pem
```

This will prompt you both for the password you used to encrypt the .pfx and a new password to use to encrypt the .pem. *Do not leave this password blank! I did and was confused as the key was not just left decrypted but rather not included in the new .pem at all*

Separate the key and the certificate in the new .pem into two different files, removing all excess lines other than the `----begin/end cert/key----` lines.

Decrypt the key by typing:

```
openssl rsa -in encryptedkey -out decryptedkey
```

And, recombine the key and cert with:

```
cat decryptedkey certificatefile > finalfile.pem
```

Now, this cert should properly authenticate a service management request to Azure:

```
import httplib
sub_id = [subid]
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('management.core.windows.net', cert_file = 'finalfile.pem')
conn.request('GET', '/%s/services/storageservices' % sub_id, headers = {'x-ms-versiojn':'2012-03-01'})

response = conn.getresponse()
print reponse.status response.reason
```